# Replacing row strings based on condition in column values

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have multiple datasets with the following format

```
head(averagetable)
   Group.1     Moving   Feeding  Standing
1 cluster1 0.05632530 0.1722892 0.7503012
2 cluster2 0.09220779 0.2644481 0.6118506
3 cluster3 0.04863636 0.1268182 0.7993182
```

I'm quite new to R and but my assignment is simple:

1) I would like to replace the name `cluster#` in `Group.1` by `Standing` in the row with the highest value in column `Standing`.

2) The name `Moving/Feeding` to the second highest value of column `Standing`

3) The name `Feeding/Moving` to the thirsd highest value of column `Standing`.

Hence the output:

```
print(averagetable)
   Group.1       Moving     Feeding   Standing
1 Moving/Feeding 0.05632530 0.1722892 0.7503012
2 Feeding/Moving 0.09220779 0.2644481 0.6118506
3 Standing       0.04863636 0.1268182 0.7993182
```

Hope this was clear enough. Note that replacing the strings using `order()` doesn't suit my needs as I have multiple dataframes and values might be different. I'm guessing `ifelse()` is the function to use but I'm guessing a `for`-loop needs to be implemented an I'm unsure on how to do that.

Comment: Are all your data frames only 3x3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just `order` `Standing` and replace the `Group.1` values

```
averagetables$Group.1[order(averagetables$Standing)] <- 
                      c("Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing")

averagetables
#         Group.1     Moving   Feeding  Standing
#1 Moving/Feeding 0.05632530 0.1722892 0.7503012
#2 Feeding/Moving 0.09220779 0.2644481 0.6118506
#3       Standing 0.04863636 0.1268182 0.7993182
```

If there are many rows and you want to change `Group.1` values only in top 3 values of `Standing` we can use `tail` to subset

```
inds <- tail(order(averagetables$Standing), 3)
averagetables$Group.1[inds] <- c("Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing")
```

This would change values only in `Group.1` for 1st highest, 2nd highest and 3rd highest values of `Standing`.

**data**

```
averagetables <- structure(list(Group.1 = c("cluster1", "cluster2", 
"cluster3"
), Moving = c(0.0563253, 0.09220779, 0.04863636), Feeding = 
c(0.1722892, 
0.2644481, 0.1268182), Standing = c(0.7503012, 0.6118506, 0.7993182
)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have multiple dataframes looking similar to this one. Values for the `Standing` column vary so I need a script with some sort of hierachical classification of the values.

Comment: @juancda4 The later part of my answer using `tail` should work for any dataframe. It will get index of top 3 values of `Standing` and use those indexes to change `Group.1` value of the dataframe.  Can you check that?

Comment: Right. Thank you!